# jQuery $.when doesn't seem to return a list of results

Tags: jquery, deferred

According to [the jQuery docs for $.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), it will return a new deferred (actually a promise) that resolves with the list of the results from the passed deferreds in the case that all the deferreds (passed to $.when) resolve without error.

So you would expect `$.when($.Deferred().resolve(1), $.Deferred().resolve(2))` to return a deferred that would resolve with the list [1, 2]. But that doesn't seem to be the case. [Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/terrycojones/Dx3Jd/3/) in which the overall $.when result is the result of the first deferred given to $.when.

I suppose I must be misunderstanding or doing something incorrectly, but I can't see what.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: I would expect the deferred to resolve with `[1]` and `[2]` (the argument lists from both deferreds

Answer (score 5):

The arguments being passed to the done handler when using `$.when` work exactly the same as `$.when`, you get one argument per promise/deferred object you pass in.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dx3Jd/4/

```
$(function () {
    make = function (x) {
        return $.Deferred().resolve(x);
    };

    $.when(make(15), make(16), make(17)).done(
        function (result1, result2, result3) {
            $('#hey').text(result1 + "-" + result2 + "-" + result3); // "15-16-17"
        }
    );
});
```

If you pass 3 arguments into `$.when`, the resulting promise object's `.done` method will receive 3 arguments.

Comment: Or, more specifically, if more than one argument was passed into `resolve`

Comment: weird, I would expect more consistency within jQuery

Comment: @JanDvorak, I agree. Life would be easier if the arguments were arrays regardless of how many params the Deferreds were resolved with.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot That and if $.when accepted an array rather than individual arguments, since it doesn't make sense to call it on a single argument.